# match string with hypen and not with hypen by using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have string like this

```
"0BzwXST-A2MuCSFpkZ05KeGJibFU";"0B3mBhsLAbBOXZlNyOX_NyOHZoUkk";
```

and i wanted to match both of these types with regex and get an array with following regex- `[A-Za-z0-9_]\w+-[-A-Za-z0-9_]\w+` but i am only getting value in array is `0BzwXST-A2MuCSFpkZ05KeGJibFU` and with `@[A-Za-z0-9_-]\w+@` i am getting three values `0BzwXST` `-A2MuCSFpkZ05KeGJibFU` `0B3mBhsLAbBOXZlNyOXNyOHZoUkk` but i don't wanted to split first one in two. how can i do that with regex in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply

```
[\w-]+
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iN3zC0/1).

Comment: Yeah that did the job. Thank ClasG